# ROR HABTM implementation with simple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I am trying to implement HABTM model with two of my database tables. Two tables are Users and Ratings. According to general structure I should have following things

- Users Model/Table
- Ratings Model/Table
- User_ratings Table

But User_ratings will have an extra column other than two ids and that will be a pre-defined string named stage. Stage will have pre-defined values such as appointment, completion e.t.c.

**My first question is does this change the role of my middle table (through table) or will we still create just a migration for middle table.**

Secondly, I am trying to implement a simple form to assign different users different ratings and my code looks like.

```
= simple_form_for @appointment, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  = f.input :start_datetime, as: :datetime_picker, input_html: {class: "datetime form-control"}
  = f.input :end_datetime, as: :datetime_picker, input_html: {class:"datetime form-control"}

  / Now here I want three fields belonging to my middle table. Something like
  = r.input :contact_id, :collection => Contact.all, :label_method => :get_contacts
  = r.inout :rating_id, :collection => Rating.all, :label_method => :get_ratings
  = r.hidden_field :stage, value: 'Appointment'
```

**The problem here is that I don't have a model for middle table and hence I am stuck with how to do it with simple_form**

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As the Ruby on Rails Style Guide suggest, don't use the basic HABTM but create your own join table. It allows you to have a better customization of the join table (see: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#has-many-through). You will have to change your relations from HABTM to `has_many through:`

Comment: Sounds valid. Any suggestion for how to show fields for middle table in appointment simple_form. Where both tables don't have any direct relation